# It's possible to decrease network consume from Selenium application?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

Today I've a scraper that was implemented in Selenium and the target website have a lot of barriers to pass, such as, Cloudflare checks, IP block, etc.

The application already pass this barriers but we are using an strategy that have a network with limits usage.

It's possible to decrease Selenium network usage? I think no, because how Selenium simulate a browser, the server will load the expected page content.

I'm just asking to be sure.

edit1: target url - https://precodahora.tcepb.tc.br/

Comment: Regarding the fact you didnt provide the actual page its hard to give advices, but disabling to load pictures reduces the traffic

Comment: oh, sry @y.y, I'll edit the question with the link

Comment: since there are a lot of images, my best bet would be to disable pictures and then you can compare the amount of traffic is used with and without pictures

Comment: @y.y maybe disable CSS can help too? Or it's insignificant? obs: I never did it before, sry if I'm asking newbie questions

Comment: dont worry, I am also no expert with selenium. I can only tell you about the advantages of disabling pictures, everything other I have no information about

Comment: @y.y got it! Ty